# C printing the same thing twice

Tags: c

how do i stop this code from printing the same things twice
./run has has
instead of it printing

```
The same arguments have been found has at 1, 2
```

it prints

```
The same arguments have been found has at 1, 2
The same arguments have been found has at 2, 1
```

```
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int r, k;

    printf("Command Line Arguments: ");
    for (r = 1; r < argc; r++)
    {
        printf("%s ", argv[r]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    for (r = 1; r < argc; r++)
    {
        for (k = 1; k < argc; k++)
        {
            if (r != k && strcmp(argv[r], argv[k]) == 0)
            {
                printf("The same arguments have been found %s at %d, %d\n", argv[r], r, k);
            } 
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (k = r; k < argc; k++)`?? For more robust checking for more than a value duplicated once, you can use a *frequency array*. Search that term on this site for ideas if you need that functionality.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: You beat me to it by a minute; I didn't see your comment when I possted. If you post it as an Answer, I'll delete mine.

Comment: @Beta no need. Glad to have you write it up.

Answer (score 2):

Simple; don't compare an argument to another argument *that has already been compared to everything.*

Instead of this:

```
for (k = 1; k < argc; k++)
```

do this:

```
for (k = r+1; k < argc; k++)
```

Answer (score -1):

You code has a bug first

you forgot

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

second, the only time it prints twice is when you input two same arguments because of your condition checking

if you input 1, 2, two different arguments

it should only print once